# Spring @Scheduled and contexts

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I'm thinking about the usage of @Scheduled annotated classes in order to run background application within a Spring web application.
I didn't understand how the application context is managed in that environment.

1. The scheduled tasks uses the same ApplicationContext of the starting
   web application?
2. Is it possible to have a brand new ApplicationContext for each
   scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

1. The scheduled tasks uses the same ApplicationContext of the starting web application? - **yes**

You use @Scheduled to annotate a method of a spring bean, not the bean class !
Spring than will call this methods depending according to the configuration provided in the annotation.

So by default the spring bean with the annotated method is part of the application context that started also the scheduler.

2.Is it possible to have a brand new ApplicationContext for each scheduled task? - **yes**

I do not see any limitations to create a new, additional application context every time the annotated method is called, but so far never had the need to do so, either.